# How to get coordinates of cursor inside canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
function getPoint ( id ){

    this.point = null

    document. getElementById( id ).addEventListener( 'mousemove', function(i) {
        this.point = i.clientX - i.target.getBoundingClientRect().left    
        console.log( 'this is' + this.point)
    } , false )

}

test = new getPoint ( 'testID' )

setInterval( function(){console.log( 'instance is' + test.point)}, 100 )
```

I want to create instance from canvasID and get coordinates of cursor inside that canvas. In this case, console.log say 'instance is undefined this is 123' but I cannot understand why test.point is 'undefined' because I think 'this.point' is the same as 'test.point'.

please tell me how to add '.addEventListener' to instance dynamic.

I hope there are few grammar mistakes.

Comment: Did you check this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/ ?

Comment: *"console.log say 'instance is undefined..."* I find that hard to believe, with the code above. "instance is null" maybe, but not "instance is undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` within your event handler callback will not be the same as `this` in `getPoint`; instead, it will be a reference to the element.

You can use a variable to remember what `this` is and then use that in the handler (see `self` below):

```
function getPoint ( id ){
    var self = this;

    self.point = null

    document. getElementById( id ).addEventListener( 'mousemove', function(i) {
        self.point = i.clientX - i.target.getBoundingClientRect().left    
        console.log( 'this is' + self.point)
    } , false )

}
```

More about `this` on my blog: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)